# Como reportar uso equivocado da fila de analise?

Tags: debate, comportamento, fechamento, sinalização, filas-de-análise

Tenho votado para fechar algumas perguntas, principalmente dos tipos Duplicata e Fora do escopo, no entanto tenho sempre me deparado com problemas, geralmente os mesmos usuários específicos, eu voto em algo e eles votam para manter em aberta.

Eu entendo que tem gente que vai vir com o papo de *"é opinião minha, por isso votei assim"*, mas não acho que seja bem por ai, por exemplo, votei para fechar essa pergunta (isso é apenas um exemplo):

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/181347

E não é o primeiro caso, inclusive tenho votado em muita coisa antiga que é totalmente off-topic (geralmente não é sobre programação) que ainda estava aberta (geralmente as pessoas deixam aberta porque acham que são perguntas úteis, mesmo que nada tenha haver com programação) e geralmente alguns usuários votam contra, ou seja votam para manter em aberto.

Eu já entrei em muitos debates tentando orientar as pessoas, mas é difícil as pessoas aceitarem, principalmente se o conteudo lhes "parece legal", eu gostaria de saber se sinalizar na pergunta detalhando o problema seria o caminho ideal.

Eu entendo perfeitamente que só porque sinalizei não significa que algo vai ser resolvido, mas creio que buscarmos evitar conflitos e reportar para quem cuida do site é o caminho ideal para evita-los.

Só gostaria de saber se isto seria uma saída, ou devo agir de outra forma quando me deparar com este tipo de problema?

Comment: Seria o caso de ter um recurso para esses tipos de situações, porque isso passa batido muitas vezes. Eu me deparo com essas situações também e nem sei como eu posso sinalizar, não sei quais caminhos ou como contatar alguém para fazer este tipo de sinalização. Espero que exista maneiras de fazer sinalização assim de modo que não dificulte o processo.

Comment: Talvez montar uma campanha ou um manual (que pode ser nessa pergunta ou pelo menos começar nela), que **forneça** alguns **critérios/orientações** por exemplo de quando manter fechada/fechar (e por qual motivo) ou deixar aberta/reabrir alguma pergunta para ajudar o pessoal na decisão das analises.

Comment: Só agora to vendo essa pergunta. Acho q a resposta do maniero é o caminho, sinalizar, além disso sempre pode procurar a moderação diretamente pelo chat se estiver confortável.

Answer (score 7):

De fato isso é ruim.

De fato a pessoa pode quase sempre alegar que é a opinião dela e tem pouco a fazer quando é isso mesmo.

O que existe de ruim e algo pode ser feito é se a pessoa tem usado as filas para chegar em medalha e segue o que já foi feito antes sem preocupação se é aquilo mesmo. Se a pessoa frequentemente faz isso algo pode ser providenciado para evitar futuros problemas.

Acredito que sinalizar na questão, se possível apontar outros casos seria interessante. Como não há muito espaço para passar informações, provavelmente seria interessante indicar isso na sinalização, podemos abrir um chat privado para passar mais informações.

De fato acho que falta ferramenta mais adequada, mas dá para lidar com isso, dê um jeito que ache adequado, o importante é resolver. Eu tendo a evitar fazer publicamente, mas não acho que seja um requisito fundamental, afinal o que a pessoa faz é público. Eu até me disponho a ver isso fora do site, mas use com parcimônia, não quero um monte de gente indo nas minhas redes choramingar por bobagem (coisa importante tudo bem, quem tem noção sabe quando é uma coisa ou não, até porque já recebi antes e já fiquei bravo e fui atrás conforme a adequação, quem não tem noção vai fazer errado de qualquer jeito).

[image: Nhonho - Olha Ele, Olha Ele]

Só tome o cuidado para não sinalizar só por discordância de opinião, isso hoje não tem muito o que fazer, uma pena.

E reforço que nem sempre poderá ser feito algo, mesmo assim vale o esforço.

O que não sei é se podemos fazer algo mais profundo, não sei se o correto seria moderador tomar uma atitude de acordo com sua opinião, o que seria coerente com a ideia de qua a opinião vale, fazer nada, o que na prática é o que acaba acontecendo por falta de orientação melhor, ou se pode-se fazer um teste manual, deixar a pessoa explicar os motivos dela para ver se ela está votando com consciência, mesmo que errado, ou está só no automático, e só depois tomar uma decisão.

Acho mesmo que precisamos de melhores recursos para lidar com certos casos, até andei ouvindo que poderá haver mais autonomia, mas ainda não sei bem em que, pode nem ser isso, ou pode nem ocorrer porque temos CM novo :) precisava de uma solução global. Concordo que certas ações prejudicam o site e cria desgaste, algumas pessoas são muito *away*, não fazem parte da comunidade, mas não sei se não é justamente o que a SE quer (ou não, pode ser que só uma "administração" específica é que queria isso).